# What is the meaning of "callback.call( value, i, value )" in jQuery's each method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, functional-programming

`each()` method in jQuery contains such a statement:

```
callback.call( value, i, value )
```

I couldn't understand what this statement means exactly.

I know what `callback` and `call` mean but I couldn't get the arguments of the function call: `(value,i,value)`. What does this mean?

The statement is used in a for block of `each()` but my question is independent of that context.

from the jQuery source:

```
for ( var value = object[0];
      i < length &&
      callback.call( value, i, value ) // <=== LOOK!
      !== false;
      value = object[++i] ) {}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `call` method exists on all functions in Javascript.  It allows you to call the function and in doing so set the value of `this` within that function.

```
function myFunc() {
    console.log(this);
}

myFunc.call(document.body);
```

In this example, `this` within `myFunc` will be `document.body`.

The first parameter of `call` is the value to be set as `this`; subsequent parameters are passed on to the function as normal parameters.  So, in your example:

```
callback.call( value, i, value )
```

this is equivalent to

```
callback(i, value)
```

except that, within the callback, `this` is now also set to `value`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

The `.each()` method calls the callback you pass it with the element (current iteration "target") as both the context object (the value of `this`) and as the second parameter.

Thus, in one of those functions:

```
$('.foo').each(function(i, elem) {
  var $this = $(this), $elem = $(elem);
```

The variables `$this` and `$elem` are interchangeable.

The first argument to `.call()` is the value to which `this` should be bound, if that wasn't clear.  The rest of the arguments to `.call()` are just passed as plain arguments to the function.

Answer (score 1):

This calls the `callback` method with `this` set to `value` (the first parameter to `call`) and with the arguments `i` and `value`.  (The other parameters to `call`)